# Add service reference in ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, service-reference

I have a problem with service reference in ASP NET Core. In Console App I have 'Add service reference' option, but in web app I don't see this functionality.

Answer (score 7):

I think a similar functionality exists when you

1. Right click your project in the solution explorer
2. under Add -> click Connected service
3. In the page that is opened, click Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider

In the pop-up that is shown, you can specify the uri, etc for the SOAP service you want to connect to.